# This expression has type (String.t * String.t * 'a) list -> 'b but an expression was expected of type 'c list OCAML

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

Hi everyone i'm having this error message and i can't find a way to solve this...

This is my function :

```
let station gares dist =
let rec station2 firstT secondT index gares final = function
  | [] -> final
  | tete::reste when (String.equal (getFirstTown tete) firstT) == true
      && (String.equal (getSecondTown tete) secondT) == true -> if (index + 1) < (List.length gares) then
          station2 (List.nth gares index) (List.nth gares (index + 1)) (index + 1) gares final@[(firstT, secondT, (getDistance tete))] reste
        else final
  | tete::reste when (String.equal (getFirstTown tete) firstT) == false
      || (String.equal (getSecondTown tete) secondT) == false -> station2 firstT secondT index gares final reste
  | _::_ -> final
in station2 (List.nth gares 0) (List.nth gares 1) 1 gares [] dist
```

and this is the signature of my function :

```
val station : string list -> (string * string * int) list -> (string * string * int) list
```

I think my error is coming from the part where i'm trying to add a new tuple to my final list :

```
final@[(firstT, secondT, (getDistance tete))]
```

I'm lost at this point, i feel like i've tryed everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from a difference of precedence between function application and the `(@)` operator.

This line:

```
station2 (List.nth gares index) (List.nth gares (index + 1))
  (index + 1) gares final@[(firstT, secondT, (getDistance tete))] reste
```

is parsed as

```
(station2 (List.nth gares index) (List.nth gares (index + 1))
  (index + 1) gares final)@([(firstT, secondT, (getDistance tete))] reste)
```

Since you want to pass the new list as argument, use parentheses:

```
station2 (List.nth gares index) (List.nth gares (index + 1))
  (index + 1) gares (final@[(firstT, secondT, (getDistance tete))]) reste
```

Or better, extract a let-binding:

```
let final2 = final@[(firstT, secondT, (getDistance tete))] in
station2 (List.nth gares index) (List.nth gares (index + 1))
  (index + 1) gares final2 reste
```

Comment: Thank you ! Worked perfectly :)